# RxJs v5 in Angular5 - clickStream.bufer( () => clickStream.throttleTime(250)) etc fails

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

How can I do the following?

```
let button = document.querySelector('.this');
let clickStream = Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click');
let multiClickStream = clickStream
   .buffer(() => { return clickStream.throttleTime(250); } )
   .map(function(list) { return list.length; })
   .filter(function(x) { return x >= 2; });
```

The error message is:

> TS2345: argument of type '()=> void' is not assignable to paramter of
>   type Observabl. Property '_isScalar' is missing in type ()=>void

Alternatives like `".buffer(function() { return clickStream.throttleTime(250); })
"` give a similar error.

I also tried `throttle(250)`, but that does not work neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you wanted to use [`bufferWhen`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-bufferWhen) that accepts a function as an argument.

Otherwise just pass the Observable directly to `buffer` without wrapping it:

```
...
.buffer(clickStream.throttleTime(250))
```